# Подключение PyQt5 к исполнению (Windows 8.1)

Tags: python-3.x, windows-8, pyqt5

Не получается правильно запустить простенький код (внизу).

Запускаю в IDLE, а в ответ выдает системную ошибку в окошке (pythonw):

> "This application failed to start because it could not gind or load
>   the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "". Reinstalling the application
>   may fix this problem."

Вопрос: как не используя IDE, через блокнотик писать простенькие GUI програмки? (tkinter хорош, но ее мало). Где и как указывать на наличие загруженной PyQt5? Если это прошлый век, то как тогда в PyCharm (на худой конец) это сделать?

P.S.

1. pip, pip3, sip (sip-4.19.1) установлены
2. В консоли запустил pip3 install pyqt5 и установил (PyQt5-5.8.1.1-5.8.0-cp35.cp36.cp37-none-win32.whl)
3. Сам пайтон установил через вебинсталлятор (Python 3.6.1rc1)

   ```
   import sys
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


   if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        w = QWidget()
        w.resize(250, 150)
        w.move(300, 300)
        w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
        w.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```

Answer (score 2):

В моём случае проблему вызывала кириллица в имени пользователя и, соответственно, пути к третьему питону. Изменение имени пользователя на состоящее только из латиницы исправило проблему. Под изменением имени пользователя в данном случае имеется создание нового, так как при штатной замене имени пользователя путь к AppData не изменяется.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил спустя сутки.
Все дело в разрядности. Сам Python был в 32, ОС в 64 и библиотека тоже.
Поставил в одну разрядность и сразу же заработало.

Comment: Для меня эта проблема все ещё не решена. Ни один ответ не подходит. Заинтересованных в решении призываю голосовать за переоткрытие [моего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744170/Проблема-this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-the), и писать свои ответы в нем, либо здесь, пока мой, халатно закрытый модератором вопрос не открыли снова.

Answer (score 0):

1. Заходим в проводник.
2. Копируем вот эту папку из своей версии питона \Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms
3. Вставляем ее напрямую в папку с версией питона(т.е. не python, а python35 например)