# Проблема This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Недавно переустановил винду и решил попробовать разобраться с питоном.

Установил питон, pycharm, создал проект, установил библиотеку PyQt5 в проект, скопировал из [гайда](http://python-3.ru/page/programmy-na-pyqt5) код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Попробовал запустить и получил ошибку

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem

В чём проблема? Как исправить?

В поиске нашел только [такую проблему](http://how-helper.ru/could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows/) с решением, но там название ошибки не совсем такое как у меня, так что и проблема наверное другая.

p.s. Мой вопрос - не дубликат [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638624/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-pyqt5-%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-windows-8-1) вопроса. У моего больше просмотров и ответ до сих пор не найден, сижу на c++, там с Qt всё в порядке

Comment: Когда вы переводили текст сообщения(или нет) вы читали вот эту строку Reinstalling the application may fix this problem в переводи типа. переустановите переложение это наверное решит эту проблему. По сути переложение не может найти какой то там  плагин так что попробуйте переустновить.

Comment: @Gleb, а вам часто помогала кнопка "Найти решение в интернете" в винде, когда возникала ошибка? Думаю нет. Переустановка помогает так же редко

Comment: Я посмотрел тот сайт на котором вы искали решение. Вы вообще побывали решить эту проблему с помощью того сайта? Потому что я думаю он вам поможет. Как я понял PyQt не может найти dll файл.

Comment: И вот еще похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638624/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-pyqt5-%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-windows-8-1?rq=1

Comment: Да, пробовал. Ничто не помогает.

Comment: Вы решили разобраться с Python или с библиотекой PyQt? Если с Python, то зачем вы беретесь сразу за PyQt?
PyQt как устанавливали? попробуйте из командной строки выполнить
pip3 install pyqt5

Comment: @van9petryk разве не очевидно что устанавливал я через pycharm? Если нет, то вот, говорю. Там есть инсталятор библиотек для каждого проекта. Он достаточно умный и устанавливает автоматически версию библиотеки которая подходит интерпритатору, с правильной разрядностью. Проблема явно не в неправильной установке чего-либо. Кроме того, винда чистая, только что переустановленная, поэтому в системе тоже вряд ли могут быть какие-то проблемы. Проблема до сих пор не решена, временно использую WxWidgets для ознакомления. Впечатления о питоне из-за проблем с использованием PyQt - очень плохие.

Comment: @TryCatch " Он достаточно умный". Видимо недостаточно. Попробуйте установить вручную. Тут проблема не в Python, а в особенностях библиотеки Qt (и неспособностью PyCharm, по видимому, корректно ее установить). У меня была похожая проблема, но немного другая область. Попробуйте все же выполнить pip3 install pyqt5. Также удалите из каталога проекта лишние файлы (те которые вы скопировали следуя инструкциям по ссылке). Попробуйте заново запустить проект (из командной строки). Отпишитесь.
Если не помогло, то тогда возможен вариант что вы скопировали в папку с проектом не тот windows.dll.

Comment: @TryCatch Если не помогло, то [отсюда](http://blog.harrix.org/article/1015) пункт 15.

Answer (score 4):

скопировал весь platforms из plugins в корень python, заработало