# Ошибка в PyQt5, как решить?

Tags: python, pyqt5

PyQt5
Пытаюсь решить проблему уже третий день.
Перерыл весь интернет, но ничего не помогает.
Ошибок в коде нет, на ПК друга все работает.
Вот ошибка:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Прошу помочь

Comment: полностью снести питон, от слова совсем. Установить, добавить в path, установить qt. И проверить на наличие русских символов в пути

Comment: PyQT5 встала криво. У меня она под ubuntu вначале не хотела нормально работать - но удалять Python, шедший вместе с OS не стал - справился без его удаления.

Comment: Извините, а что значит "Криво"? И как поставить нормально?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638624/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-pyqt5-%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-windows-8-1

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подключение PyQt5 к исполнению (Windows 8.1)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638624/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-pyqt5-%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > 1. Заходим в проводник.
   > 2. Копируем вот эту папку из своей версии питона \Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms
   > 3. Вставляем ее напрямую в папку с версией питона(т.е. не python, а python35 например)
2. > В моём случае проблему вызывала кириллица в имени пользователя и,
   > соответственно, пути к третьему питону. Изменение имени пользователя
   > на состоящее только из латиницы исправило проблему. Под изменением
   > имени пользователя в данном случае имеется создание нового, так как
   > при штатной замене имени пользователя путь к AppData не изменяется.
3. > Проблему решил спустя сутки. Все дело в разрядности. Сам Python был в
   > 32, ОС в 64 и библиотека тоже. Поставил в одну разрядность и сразу же
   > заработало.

---

[source](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638624/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-pyqt5-%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-windows-8-1)