# Ошибка при запуске QT

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt

При запуске приложения на `QT` возникает ошибка:

> Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""  This
> application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be
> initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Гуглили текст ошибки? По-моему, тут время от времени возникают вопросы по этой ошибке

Comment: @gil9red видел на англоязычном stackowerflow, но там работа с директориями, который у меня нет. Для большего эффекта это вообще не мой ПК, а я пытаюсь помочь своему другу по ту сторону экрана

Comment: Вы сделали приложение и отправили его другу и у него та ошибка? Или у друга ошибка а он попросил помощи? Если первое, то это логично -- для Qt нужные его же DLL

Comment: @gil9red, второй вариант

Comment: вы запускаете `exe`-шник ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs, нет, файл .py

Comment: попробуйте ответы из этого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638624/Подключение-pyqt5-к-исполнению-windows-8-1