# PyQt5 не работает

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Недавно установил PyQt5 на Windows 10. Хотел посмотреть готовое приложение на нем, но оно не запускается. Выдает следующую ошибку:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Пробовал переустанавливать пакеты, не помогло. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Покажите ваш тестовый пример.

Comment: И укажите операционную систему.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638624/Подключение-pyqt5-к-исполнению-windows-8-1

Comment: Чуть позже попробуй создать нового пользователя по совету с темы выше. Если поможет - сразу сообщу.

Comment: Как вы устанавливали PyQt5 ? Опубликуйте ваше тестовое приложение.

Comment: Устанавливал через pip, приложение не важно, т.к. даже не получается импортировать Qt5